# The collection goes back to the original spot

Tags: collections

https://youtu.be/5ymXHNSNTZo

As you can see in this video, although I move the collection, it goes back to the original spot. What am I missing?

Comment: Presumably that's an third-party addon not part of Blender so you should ask the addon author.

Comment: Please give us any extra context you can, to help us get a clue. Just checking.. there's no key-framing on anything, is there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think here is happening what you think is happening.
Sometimes it's hard to see what's actually going on in a 2D representation of a 3D world. To get a better idea of how to place the object, I would suggest using at least 2 different orthographic views.

As a shortcut, you can also use the quad view by pressing `ctrl + alt + Q` in the 3d viewport (press `ctrl + alt + Q` again to leave this view).
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#quad-view

Now, if you move your object in the upper right 3D view as before, you will see exactly where it actually goes.

You have a way better control if you move your object in the orthographic view. Sometimes this is the right way to go.

Comment: I see. 3D environment is tricky indeed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)
Now, if the Answer was of value, then have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers